# WSDL Soap Port without handler

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I added a service to my project in visual basic to connect to soap api of magento.
The connection seems to work but in my wsdl I havn't got the handler Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler. So I can't use it.

```
<service name="MagentoService">
<port name="Port" binding="typens:Binding">
<soap:address location="http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/"/></port></service>
```

What I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A library to help when working with .net and Magento's API:

- https://github.com/molotovbliss/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi

Also be sure to enable WS-I compliance:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/wsi_compliance.html
- http://alanstorm.com/magentos_wsi_compliant_api

You may also want to try to disable WSDL Caching as well.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/303514/158325

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. I have port name without handler "Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler"

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but today I went through this problem. I could not figure it out, but I got it fixed. I'll explain and maybe someone more experienced can understand what's going on.

in **Mage_Api_Model_Server** we have the following function:

```
public function run()
{
    $this->getAdapter()->run();
}
```

The return of this function is an instance of **Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Adapter_Soap** and if we debug it we will get the following result:

```
public function run()
{
    //$this->getAdapter()->run();
    echo $this->getAdapter()->getHandler();
}
```

> output: **'Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler'**

So far so good, but if we go in **Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Adapter_Soap** in the **run()** method and give an echo in **$this->getHandler()** we get a null return.

So, since getHandler does not work, in the _getWsdlConfig () method, I made a small change. not a solution, just could not find the root of the problem and that's how I found it to not break the API. If anyone knows the solution to the problem I am very grateful

> app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php

```
protected function _getWsdlConfig()
{
    $wsdlConfig = Mage::getModel('api/wsdl_config');
    //$wsdlConfig->setHandler($this->getHandler());
    $wsdlConfig->setHandler($this->getHandler('Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler'))
        ->init();
    return $wsdlConfig;
}
```

Before they comment, I did not change the core. I rewrote the method